# .htaccess causing $_GET to return NULL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

I am trying to pass a variable from one page to another via my url.  The structure of the urls looks like this `http://localhost:8888/test_portfolio?location=ignite_rockford`.

Here's the relevant info from my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php?/$1?$1=$1
</IfModule></code>
```

The problem seems to be with this line: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php?/$1?$1=$1`, but I don't know what to do.  If I add `.php` after test_portfolio, then it works, but otherwise when I dump `$_GET['location']` I get `NULL`.

Oh yeah, I'm retrieving `$_GET` with `$location = $_GET["location"];`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to remove the `.php`, you can just add it and copy the query string with `[QSA]` tag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` takes care of matching files. `-d` does the same for directories.

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs will go from:

`/test` to `/test.php?/test?test=test` are you sure this is what you want? (it looks malformed, among other things)

Usually you'll write a Router like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?__url=$1 [QSA]
```

This will give you a `GET` parameter `__url` with the original path. `[QSA]` will allow you to still accept all original query parameters, like `location`.